# Break single column into multiple columns based on condition for rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to write code in R that breaks a single column into multiple columns based on a set condition, where rows 1-n remain the first column, rows n-n2 become the second column, rows n2-n3 become the third, etc.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
       X1
1   Nov 1
2   task2
3   task3
4  Oct 31
5   task2
6   task3
7   task4
8   task5
9  Oct 29
10  task2
```

And here is the desired output:

```
       X1       X2       X3
1   Nov 1   Oct 31   Oct 29
2   task2    task2    task2
3   task3    task3       NA 
4      NA    task4       NA 
5      NA    task5       NA
```

The context of the above is that I am importing the history of a to-do list, cleaning the data (both already done), and finally breaking it into columns based on date. The date format is always the first three letters of a given month followed by the day number as shown above. I have tried a number of ideas to no avail.

This is the closest I have found to a solution, but it is not in R: [Split column into multiple columns when a row starts with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689250/split-column-into-multiple-columns-when-a-row-starts-with-a-string)

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Solution 3 from Ludwig worked beautifully, thanks so much!

I did have an issue where the initial code for the pattern would sometimes treat tasks incorrectly as dates for new columns (ex: when a task was "Decide on..." where the Dec in Decide was treated as the abbreviation for December).

I came up with a hard-coded work around, but Ludwig came back with a more elegant solution which has been incorporated into the solution below. It eliminates the issue entirely.

Thanks so much again Ludwig!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to approach this problem. Personally, I think **solution 3** is the best. Note that filling rows with a loop as done in **solution 1** can be a very slow process.

First create the to-do list as a data.frame, and defined the pattern of month names. This is the basis for each solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
            X1 = c(
                    "Nov 1",
                    "task2",
                    "task3",
                    "Oct 31",
                    "task2",
                    "task3",
                    "task4",
                    "task5",
                    "Oct 29",
                    "task2"
            )
    )
pattern <- paste(paste(month.abb, "\\d+"), collapse = "|")

pattern
#[1] "Jan \\d+|Feb \\d+|Mar \\d+|Apr \\d+|May \\d+|Jun \\d+|Jul \\d+|Aug \\d+|Sep \\d+|Oct \\d+|Nov \\d+|Dec \\d+"
```

### Solution 1:

A loop fills the values in `df$month` with the correct month name for each task.

```
df <- df |> mutate(month = X1)

i <- 1
while (i <= length(df$month)) {
        if (!grepl(pattern, df$month[i])) {
                df$month[i] <- df$month[i - 1]
        }
        i <- i + 1
}
```

With some workarounds it is then possible to have the data in a desired output. I noticed, that it is not exactly what you wanted, but it's arguebly easier to work with if you have the month names as column names.

```
df <- df |>
        filter(!grepl(pattern, X1)) |>
        pivot_wider(names_from = month,
                    values_from = X1,
                    values_fn = list) |> 
        unlist(recursive = F)

df <- sapply(df, '[', seq(max(lengths(df)))) |> data.frame()

df
#  Nov.1 Oct.31 Oct.29
#1 task2  task2  task2
#2 task3  task3   <NA>
#3  <NA>  task4   <NA>
#4  <NA>  task5   <NA>
```

### Solution 2:

This one is a more elegant solution and returns a data frame as you described it.

```
df <- df |> 
        mutate(grp = cumsum(grepl(pattern, X1))) |> 
        pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = X1, values_fn = list) |> 
        unlist(recursive = F)

df <- sapply(df, '[', seq(max(lengths(df)))) |> data.frame()

df
#     X1     X2     X3
#1 Nov 1 Oct 31 Oct 29
#2 task2  task2  task2
#3 task3  task3   <NA>
#4  <NA>  task4   <NA>
#5  <NA>  task5   <NA>
```

### Solution 3:

Here, we combine the elegance of **solution 2** with the convenience of **solution 1**. Personally, I like this the most. Hope it helps!

```
df <- df |> 
        mutate(grp = cumsum(grepl(pattern, X1))) |> 
        mutate(grp = grep(pattern, X1, value = T), .by = grp) |> 
        filter(!grepl(pattern, X1)) |> 
        pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = X1, values_fn = list) |> 
        unlist(recursive = F)

df <- sapply(df, '[', seq(max(lengths(df)))) |> data.frame()

df
#  Nov.1 Oct.31 Oct.29
#1 task2  task2  task2
#2 task3  task3   <NA>
#3  <NA>  task4   <NA>
#4  <NA>  task5   <NA>
```

Comment: `month.abb` is a much cleaner way to get `pattern` avoiding `substring()`

Comment: Didn't know that it existed. Will implement it in the solution, thanks!

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much!!! I am using solution 3 as using the dates as the column headers was indeed the desired outcome. Thanks!!!

My puny R brain is struggling to comprehend how this is done; is it right that what is happening in the code is creating a pattern vector; transforming the single column dataframe into a list; splitting the list according to the month pattern (using the month prefix as filter); then transforming the new lists into the columns in a dataframe?

Comment: One issue I ran into was that the pattern based on month.abb was making columns of tasks where the task name was "Decide on ..." or "Maybe try...", as the months were abbreviated as Jan|Feb|...May|...Dec|.

To get around that I changed the pattern code to pattern <- paste("Jan ","Feb ","Mar ","Apr ","May ","Jun ","Jul ","Aug ","Sep ","Oct ","Nov ","Dec ", sep="|"), such that the months had a space after. That's working without a hitch so far, as I never write a month abbreviation into my tasks.

Comment: To get a better understand of what is happening, you can run the segments one-by-one. E.g. run `df |> mutate(grp = cumsum(grepl(pattern, X1)))` alone, then `df |> mutate(grp = cumsum(grepl(pattern, X1))) |> mutate(grp = grep(pattern, X1, value = T), .by = grp)`, etc. I think it explains it bettter than I might do it with words.

Comment: But I'll try: Your to-do list is the only column in the dataframe. Then, a 2nd column is created by `mutate` that exploits the fact that the boolean value `TRUE` is represented or mathematically equivalent of the numeric `1`, and `FALSE` is `0`, respectively: `grepl(pattern, X1)` returns a boolean vector, whether the pattern is present on each position. E.g: `"Nov 1",  "task2",  "task3", "Oct 31"` results in `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE`. The cumulative sum of this would then be `1, 1, 1, 2`.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Brilliant way of doing it, thanks so much!!

Comment: The 2nd `mutate` step then transforms the column containing the 1s, 2s and 3s in the corresponding month from the initial column in their group. The `filter` is applied to remove the dates from the initial to-do list column. `pivot_wider` transforms the dataframe from a long format to a wide format, meaning each unique date becomes a new column, which has each task that belonged to this date as values. `values_fn = list) |> unlist(recursive = F)` and everything that follows is a workaround, because R does not like dataframes which columns have different lengths. Hope it is somewhat clear..

Comment: And about the pattern. If you don't want to hardcode it I would suggest to try this: `pattern <- paste(paste(month.abb, "\\d+"), collapse = "|")`. This will make sure that only month abbreviations followed by a space and number will be matched. I'll put it in the solution.

Comment: Yea, that's far more elegant than my solution. I'll update it in my main post too. Thanks again for helping me out and explaining everything!